# socat, need example using af_inet sock_stream to get data from machine

Tags: socat

Need example to connect using PF_INET and SOCK_STREAM via socat program.
When I try:

```
sudo socat socket-connect:af_inet:0:192.168.0.10 STDIO
```

I get:

```
[11458] E exiting on signal 11
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: When you increase logging level using option -d you will see that this SIGSEGV follows a syntax error.

Comment: Checkout Socats man page, paragraph about SOCKET-CONNECT: "The two socket parameters have to be specified  by  int numbers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try is establishing a TCP connecting using low level functions. Therefore you will need a port number. For this example solution I take 80.

Assuming you have good reason not to use the ready to use TCP address the solution might be something like:

```
socat SOCKET-CONNECT:2:6:"x0050 xC0A8000A x00000000 x00000000" STDIO
```

Meaning of parameters:
2...AF_INET
6...TCP
The third parameter is data to construct the socket address, for AF_INET we need a struct sockaddr_in; the first two bytes of the record specify its length and are implicitly generated by Socat from the given data.
x0050...port in hex, network byte order
xC0A8000A...hex for 192.168.0.10
x00000000...padding to length 16

Hope this helps!

Comment: Need connect to machine (linux 2.4) with defined: session: socket - Unix domain socket 1.0/smp for NET4.0. Machine is client, need write server. There was no response for 'nc -l (port)' or 'socat TCP4-LISTEN:port' and similar.